# waf automating qt configuration

Tags: python, qt, wsh, waf

I am using waf wscript for making a project. The problem I am facing is including the qt specific headers: lib and libpath. I have fair knowledge of pkg-config tool. There are .pc files in /usr/lib/pkg-config directory which help in automatically expanding the needed directory. But there are no .pc files for qt. QT libs were installed using synaptic.
Is there a way to avoid writing all include paths and lib directory in the wscript configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waf comes with tool to support QT4. have you looked at the demo showing how to use waf with QT4?

http://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/demos/qt4/wscript